# Sqlalchemy orm strategies _load_for_state taking huge amount of time

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, lazy-loading, flask-sqlalchemy

I have an application which was running very quickly. Let's say it took 10 seconds to run. All it does is read a csv, parse it, and store some of the info in sqlalchemy objects which are written to the database.  (We never attempt to read the database, only to write).

After adding a many to many relationship to the entity we are building and relating it to an address entity which we now build, the time to process the file has increased by an order of magnitude. We are doing very little additional work: just instantiating an address and storing it in the relationship collection on our entity using append.

Most of the time appears to be lost in `_load_for_state` as can be seen in the attached profiling screenshot:
[image]

I'm pretty sure this is unnecessary lost time, because it looks like it is trying to do some loading even though we never make any queries of the database (we always instantiate new objects and save them in this app).

Anyone have an idea how to optimize sqlalchemy here?

**update**

I tried setting `SQLALCHEMY_ECHO = True` just to see if it is doing a bunch of database reads, or maybe some extra writes. Bizarrely, it only accesses the database itself at the same times it did before (following a `db.session.commit()`). I'm pretty sure all this extra time is not being spent due to database access.

Comment: Does [`lazy='noload'`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html) help at all?

Comment: my previous comment was misleading. `noload` had an effect visible in call graph. however, the same method continues to dominated the time expenditure, and the time expenditure continues to be extreme

Comment: Since this is performance related, it's crucial that you provide a [mcve], including test data.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. I'll put something together. Thanks

Comment: @melchoir55, did you figure this out? I am facing the same issue.